# How to Avoid Repeated Number in Random Generation WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, random

I want random number in one array.

```
array like this int[] random={"1","2","3","4","5"};
```

I want to take these number randomly. its working fine but value are repeating. 
i don't wont repeated value. i want random number without repeating same number.

I am using this code to get Random Number,

```
Random randomnumber=new Rambom();
int number= randomnumber.Next(random.Length());
```

if anyone know tell me idea to do this,

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the random array is the source of the numbers, you could remove the numbers as you get them, therefore removing the duplication altogether :-

```
    List<int> random = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random randomnumber = new Random();

        int number = random[randomnumber.Next(0, random.Count - 1)];

        random.Remove(number);

        MyList.Items.Add(number);
    }
```

Comment: Side note: it will be inefficient for more elements.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Diston soultion is good enough, but with more numbers is inefficient. One simple way to generate random unique numbers is to add them to HashSet. Snippet:

```
        HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            hashSet.Add(rand.Next(5));
        }
        foreach (var item in hashSet.AsEnumerable()) //hashSet.ToList() to get list
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Later on if you want another list with random array - shuffle it. One of the best way to do it is [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Snippet:

```
public static void Shuffle<T> (Random rand, IList<int> list)
{
    int n = list.Count;
    while (n > 1) 
    {
        int k = rand.Next(n--);
        //swapping values
        T temp = list[n]; 
        list[n] = list[k];
        list[k] = temp;
    }
}
```

Sadly, there is no built-in functionality for this.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and see if you have already added the number. If you have, create new random. Then check again.

Comment: int number= randomnumber.Next(random.Length());  this code looped 5 times it will give same value like this 1,1,4,4,2. i want like this 1,4,3,2,5 randomly without repeating same value.

Answer (score 0):

i am thinking about deleting the already selected values from the random array.
so you can search for "number" in your "random array" and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to avoid duplicates is simply to swap the found number with the last element of the array and then reduce the size of array by 1.